# Using MySQLConnector in C# dependencies

Tags: c#, mysql, dll

I'm using MySQLConnector and C# to connect to my database.
Everything runs fine, but when i try my program at another machine i get an "Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data" error.
I just copied the .exe out of the Release directory from Visual Studio to the Machine and thought this would do it.
What is required to get MySQLConnector to work on other Machines?
Do i need to install MySQLConnector to use it or just copy some .dll's?
I tried to install the MySQLConnector.msi on the other machine, but the code does still not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the MySQL objects are installed on the target machine.  You can do this by manually or installing the objects are perhaps the easiest is to create a click once installer package where the MySQL objects are included.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just copying files anyway, copy everything from the `bin` folder to make sure you get all of your program's dependencies.

One of the files in there should be `mysql.data.dll`.

Comment: thanks!
I made it a little different: There were no DLL's in my bin, so i downloaded the .NET & Mono .zip package from the official site and found the mysql.data.dll and copied that into the right directory

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, you need to set "Copy Local" property of the DLL MySql.Data (and any other dependencies) to "True" by following this instruction:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t1zz5y8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Then when you compile the project, you will see file MySql.Data.dll in the same folder as the .exe, you will need to copy that .exe and any other DLL files to other machines.